# Filter posts from a certain category, using query_posts() in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

While using `query_posts()`  to filter category on a wordpress main query, the below query is appended to the main query:

```
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (6,19,4501,5482,7401) ).
```

The code I added is:

```
query_posts( $query_string . '&cat=4496,6,19' );
```

I need the post from categories `'4496,6,19'` only, and not `'6,19,4501,5482,7401'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `query_posts( $query_string . '&cat=4496,6,19,-6,-19,-4501,5482,7401' );`

Reference: [JamesVL wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/User%3aJamesVL/query_posts)

You can also try the following in [this link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query_posts-include-and-exclude-categories)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) at all costs. This is not just me, it comes straight from the codex. I quote

> This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

You can achieve what you need by simply using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

```
function my_home_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query- >is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '4496,6,19' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_home_category' );
```

Add this to your functions.php. This will only display the selected categories on the home page. You can change the conditionals as needed

Comment: Was my answer useful, if yes, please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the check mark next to my answer :-)